# Embed JavaScript into Script-block

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following construct, which obviously is just HTML:

```
<script type="text/html" id="abc">
//... some text
</script>
```

Now I want to put some JavaScript into it. So it would look like:

```
<script type="text/html" id="abc">
//...
    <script type="text/javascript">
       alert("Hello!");
    </script>
//...
</script>
```

Of course, it won't work, as I would close the `script`-tag, before the whole code block ends.

So, is there a proper way to embed JavaScript into my `script`-block?

Comment: you don't need the second script tags

Comment: @ztadic91 First tags are text/html. Second are text/javascript. Second ones are required.

Comment: @ztadic91: The OP is probably trying to include scripts into some text/html templates.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Yes, that's true.

Comment: @ztadic91 is right, there is no need for the second block tag. To insert javascript code inside script block, you must just insert the javascript

Comment: @YerkoPalma: The OP is trying to include scripts into some text/html templates. So simply leaving out the tag won't work.

Comment: I guess you can't do this hard coded in the html, if you want to use a tag `</script>` inside a <script> tag you have to do `"</"+"script>"`

Comment: @Hacketo: Javascript won't run in the outer script tag.

Comment: @Cerbrus did I say that ?

Comment: That `"</"+"script>"` will just render as exactly that when the template is used. The concatenation can _only_ take place if that bit is interpreted as JS.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm not saying to replace the end tag with this trick. As I said, it can't be done hard coded in the html.

Answer (score -2):

if you really want to manually create `Script` tag inside `<script>` using JavaScript... then here is a way to achieve the same:

It won't work with `text/html`, please try as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="abc">
//...
    var script=document.createElement('script');
    script.type='text/javascript';
    script.src=url;

    $("body").append(script);
//...
</script>
```

Comment: Nope, nope, nope. JavaScript inside `<script type="text/html">` won't run.

Comment: hey @Cerbrus, answer is edited now

Comment: Please read the question again and have a look at what the OP is trying to do.